# Read file into string - Java

Tags: java, file, io

I want to read an entire file into a string. The file however is in the program arguments. I have been trying to use Scanner in order to:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(args[0]);  
        scan.useDelimiter("\\Z");  
        String content = scan.next(); 
        System.out.println(content);
```

My result is just the name of the file that is in "args[0]" instead of the actual contents of the file.

I figured a loop would not work since I am not hardcoding the file into the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. If you want a `Scanner` wrapping a `File` pass a `File` in the constructor. Change this

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(args[0]);
```

to

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
```

The constructor for [`Scanner(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.lang.String%29) says,

> Constructs a new `Scanner` that produces values scanned from the specified string.

While the constructor for [`Scanner(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.File%29) says,

> Constructs a new `Scanner` that produces values scanned from the specified file.